# How to run for-loop for each occurence of line.startswith(mystring) in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using Python 3.x in Windows 10.

In my case, there are DAT files which include lines for specific features of technical drawings.

"B   " represents bendline. So in any file, there can be more than 1 bendline.
I'm calculating distances for center of holes to these bendlines individually. But my code works for only first bendline.

```
while True:
    mydir = input("Path:") + "\\"
    root = glob.iglob(mydir + '**/*', recursive = True)
    for filename in root:
        if filename.endswith(".DAT"):
            with open(filename, "r") as f, \
                mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as s:
                if s.find(b"B        ") != -1:
                    print("\n{}".format(
                                    os.path.basename(filename).split("_R", 2)[0]))
                    for line in f:
                        if line.startswith("B        "):
                            try:
                                bx1 = float(line.split()[1].strip())
                                bx2 = float(line.split()[3].strip())
                                by1 = float(line.split()[2].strip())
                                by2 = float(line.split()[4].strip())
                                degr = float(line.split()[5].strip())

                            except:
                                bx1 = 0
                                bx2 = 0
                                by1 = 0
                                by2 = 0
                                degr = "NULL"
                            try:
                                m = (by2 - by1) / (bx2 - bx1)
                            except:
                                m = 0

                            bline = "({},{}) - ({},{}):".format(bx1,by1,bx2,by2)
                            print(bline)


                        if line.startswith("P"):
                            try:
                                thickness = float((line.split("P")[1]).split("x")[0])
                            except:
                                thickness = 0

                        if line.startswith("H"):
                            try:
                                dx = float(line.split()[1].strip())
                                dy = float(line.split()[2].strip())
                                diameter = float(line.split()[3].strip())

                                d = round(abs(-m*dx+dy+m*bx1-by1) / math.sqrt(m*m + 1) - (diameter/2),2)
                            except:
                                dx = 0
                                dy = 0
                                diameter = 0
                                d = 0

                            if dx == dy == diameter == d == 0 or bx1 == bx2 == by1 == by2 == 0:
                                print("Something went wrong...")
                                break
                            if d < 2*thickness:
                                print("---------------------------------------------------------")
                                print("Distance: ({}) mm.".format(d))
                                print("---------------------------------------------------------")
```

so I tried to use nested loops for same loop criteria, but this time I cannot provide result.

```
while True:
    mydir = input("Path:") + "\\"
    root = glob.iglob(mydir + '**/*', recursive = True)
    for filename in root:
        if filename.endswith(".DAT"):
            with open(filename, "r") as f, \
                mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as s:
                if s.find(b"B        ") != -1:
                    print("\n{}".format(
                                    os.path.basename(filename).split("_R", 2)[0]))
                    for line in f:
                        if line.startswith("B        "):
                            try:
                                bx1 = float(line.split()[1].strip())
                                bx2 = float(line.split()[3].strip())
                                by1 = float(line.split()[2].strip())
                                by2 = float(line.split()[4].strip())
                                degr = float(line.split()[5].strip())

                            except:
                                bx1 = 0
                                bx2 = 0
                                by1 = 0
                                by2 = 0
                                degr = "NULL"
                            try:
                                m = (by2 - by1) / (bx2 - bx1)
                            except:
                                m = 0

                            bline = "({},{}) - ({},{}):".format(bx1,by1,bx2,by2)
                            print(bline)

                            for line in f:
                                if line.startswith("P"):
                                    try:
                                        thickness = float((line.split("P")[1]).split("x")[0])
                                    except:
                                        thickness = 0

                                    for line in f:
                                        if line.startswith("H"):
                                            try:
                                                dx = float(line.split()[1].strip())
                                                dy = float(line.split()[2].strip())
                                                diameter = float(line.split()[3].strip())

                                                d = round(abs(-m*dx+dy+m*bx1-by1) / math.sqrt(m*m + 1) - (diameter/2),2)
                                            except:
                                                dx = 0
                                                dy = 0
                                                diameter = 0
                                                d = 0

                                        if dx == dy == diameter == d == 0 or bx1 == bx2 == by1 == by2 == 0:
                                            print("Something went wrong...")
                                            break
                                        if d < 2*thickness:
                                            print("---------------------------------------------------------")
                                            print("Distance: ({}) mm.".format(d))
                                            print("---------------------------------------------------------")
```

dat file example:

```
B        0         221.5     278.6     221.5     157.8     
B        0         139.7     278.6     139.7     152.9     
H        217.1     249.2     28.6      
H        139.3     270.7     25.4      
H        61.5      249.2     28.6      
H        234.6     180.2     17.5      
H        214.8     25.4      17.5
```

I am stuck in. Can you please illuminate?

Comment: Is your input file a text file ? Why do you use mmap.mmap() ... ? too complicate :/

Comment: I cannot work with If (string in file): method, so I used it for searching files only include bendline.

And answer is yes. All dat files are text file...

Comment: Well, I've tried to understand what you want to compute. In your test case, you have 2 bendlines and 5 holes. You want to calculate distances of the 5 holes to the 2 bendlines ? Am I right ?
I think you can read the file first, putting bendlines into a list and holes into an other one. Then proceed to the calculation.

Comment: I'd better try, whether I can reach exact result. Actually I firstly focused to get result while accessing file. 

I have lots of dat. So repeatedly I need to create list, and overwrite them. But I'm going to try. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example how to read the input file once, then proceed to the calculations. I don't know about the "T    " thickness record. And I pick up formula from the original post.

```
import math

bendlines = []
holes = []

with open(filename, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("B        "):
            try:
                # use the power of Python ;-)
                bx1, bx2, by1, by2, degr = map(float, line.split()[1:])

                m = (by2 - by1) / (bx2 - bx1)

                bendlines.append((bx1, bx2, by1, by2, m))
                bline = "({},{}) - ({},{}):".format(bx1, by1, bx2, by2)
                print(bline)

            except:
                pass # ignore calculation and parsing errors
        elif line.startswith("H"):
            try:
                dx, dy, diameter = map(float, line.split()[1:])
                holes.append((dx, dy, diameter))
            except:
                pass

# calculation
for bendline in bendlines:
    for hole in holes:
        bx1, bx2, by1, by2, m = bendline
        dx, dy, diameter = hole

        d = round(abs(-m*dx+dy+m*bx1-by1) / math.sqrt(m*m + 1) - (diameter/2),2)

        print("bendline %r with hole  %r => %f" % (bendline, hole, d))
```

Comment: I'm going to merge your code with mine. And I think it will be useful for me than expected. Thanks.
However, I have an issue with your code:
For 1 single file, your code works perfect. But with 2 or more files, it is complicated. It appends all bendlines, holes etc and code runs forever. What about this situation?

Comment: You can "reset" bendlines and holes arrays with `bendlines = []
holes = []` (lines 3 and 4 of my snippet)